# R Analyzing spatial distribution of tweets

Tags: r, twitter, gis

Analyzing tweets with `hashtags` provides an interesting insight into public opinion and issues. In this regard I did some research as to what `packages` are available for downloading `tweets` as a `dataframe`. Some of these packages are `rtweet` and `twitterR` which are awesome for social data analytics.

Now my question is it possible to get the `spatial information` (such as approximate coordinates, city, street and etc.) on tweets using `R`?

For example, a natural hazard takes place and I am interested in gathering information on `communities` affected by it.

Comment: I am not completely sure what you mean. Do you wish to extract any information that could be linked to a location? Or do you want the location from where the user was at the time of posting the tweet (if they have this option enabled)? `rtweet` has some interaction with the Google Maps API, for example the function `lookup_coords`, is something like that what you are looking for?

Comment: @WietsedeVries, yes I think having info on where the user was at the time of posting the tweet would be ideal. But since I assume not every user would have this option enabled then extracting information that could be linked to a location such as city or street would be more practical.

Comment: Hmmm, that is going to be difficult. I have to assume that in most cases the location will be written in plain text so somehow an algorithm would have to be smart enough to recognize any text (single word or multiple words) that would indicate a city, street, country, coordinate, province, state, postal code, etc. Besides, addresses come in all shapes and sizes, especially between countries.